# Why does "disj" from miniKanren work in Scheme but not in Racket?

Tags: scheme, racket, logic-programming, minikanren

I was working with the minikanren library for Racket, but wanted to use the "disj" and "conj" operators. I want to be able to more explicitly declare whether I am using disj or conj for the sake of legibility rather than have to parse through a conde expression, especially once the expressions become more complicated. I copied the source from "The Reasoned Schemer":

```
(define (append∞ s∞ t∞)
  (cond
    ((null? s∞) t∞)
    ((pair? s∞)
     (cons (car s∞)
           (append∞ (cdr s∞) t∞)))
    (else (λ ()
            (append∞ t∞ (s∞))))))

(define (disj2 g1 g2)
  (λ (s)
    (append∞ (g1 s) (g2 s))))

(define-syntax disj
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(disj) '()]
    [(disj g) g]
    [(disj g0 g ...) (disj2 g0 (disj g ...))]))
```

This works properly with the first two cases

```
> (run* (x) (disj (== 'foo x)))
'(foo)
```

but only returns the first result when using more than one goal:

```
> (run* (x) (disj (== 'foo x) (== 'bar x) (== 'foobar x)))
'(foo)
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hrmph. I can't seem to reproduce that behavior.

When I clone the [TRS/2e repo](https://github.com/TheReasonedSchemer2ndEd/CodeFromTheReasonedSchemer2ndEd), add both

```
#lang racket
(provide (all-defined-out))
```

to the top of `trs2-impl.scm`, run that file, and then try your test program I see the expected result:

```
; 
; Welcome to Racket v7.9.0.3 [cs].
; 
trs2-impl.scm> (run* (x) (disj (== 'foo x) (== 'bar x) (== 'foobar x)))
'((foo) (bar) (foobar))
```

Do you see different behavior? If so, then we could look deeper. Do you know which version of Racket you're using? I don't think that will matter, but just in case.

Comment: Ah, I see. I think the issue was that I used a hybrid of the standard Racket minikanren library,  combined with the functions needed for the disj function on top of the standard library... using the entire trs2 implementation of minikanren seems to work properly. Thanks!